# Partial iteration and inverse iteration of $e^x$

Tags: exponential-function, function-and-relation-composition, tetration, fractional-iteration

> Find the general $f^n(x)$ where
>
> $f^1(x)=e^x$
>
> $f^{a}(f^{b}x)=f^{(a+b)}(x)$
>
> where $n,x\in\mathbb R$

I'm fairly confident that no two $f^n(x)$ with different values of $n$ will intersect, since then we could use the argument that if $f^n(x)=x$ at some point $A$, then $f^m(x)=x$ at the same point $A$, and $x$ does not intersect $e^x$. So $f^n(x)\ne f^m(x)$ at any point.

*P.S.* I'm not sure what tags to add for this, so add them as you see fit

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300687/solving-for-f), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-square-root), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300687/solving-for-f#comment4733521_2300687).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I'm looking for a general solution, not just $n=0.5$

Comment: Understand one value and you'll understand most of it.

Comment: See also: [Uniquely extended fractional iterations of $\exp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380042/uniquely-extended-fractional-iterations-of-exp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may apply a [Newton series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series) as [this answer shows](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/44727#44727) to yield:

$$f^\alpha(x)=f^{\lceil\alpha\rceil}(f^{\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil}(x))=f^{\lceil\alpha\rceil}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^k(x)\right)$$

other neat forms:

$$f^\alpha(x)=f^{\lceil\alpha\rceil}\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom {\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil}n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil-n}{\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil-k}\binom nk(-1)^{n-k}f^k(x)\right]$$

---

note the use of $\alpha-\lceil\alpha\rceil$ to avoid the calculation of half iterations of functions that are super linear with base greater than $e^{1/e}.$

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the exponential to base $e$ - isn't then the last term $f^k(x)$ already for small $k$ a bit adventurous?